# Open Embedded Word Doc using VBA Recorded Macro

Tags: vba

I'm trying to open an embedded word doc from an excel doc using a recorded macro.

When I try to run the macro, I get runtime error 438, `object doesn't support this property or method`,  Can anyone help?

It's the first part of the code - it looks like this:

```
Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
```

Help appreciated.

Thanks